# Possible to show aggregate votes in a tooltip on a markercluster?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm building an interface that would take poll data in and show some results over a marker cluster using Mapbox but I don't have any experience with it.

The interface would look much like https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-markercluster/

If you click on the cluster instead of zooming in a tooltip would show up with a breakdown of (yes/no) votes in a pie chart like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/hv4c8708wlhe4mt/Screenshot%202014-11-30%2015.27.53.png?dl=0

In the GeoJSON data I was thinking each data point would have a property to state the vote value and somehow I could look at them in aggregate at the cluster level

geoJSON structure

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "vote": "yes" //no
  }
}
```

Is this possible using these libraries and geoJSON data structure? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Leaflet markers clusterer can be used to show directly pie charts on the map. 
An example is visible on [this map showing the breakdown of accidents in Oslo](http://bl.ocks.org/gisminister/10001728). The code behind is rather well explained and could be adapted for your case.

Answer (score 0):

> Possible to show aggregate votes in a tooltip on a markercluster?

The 1-1 sum of markers are just one type of aggregation.

What about aggregating a sub-property, in a sum, an average or something ?